# Show only drawerToggleIndicator and Title in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I want my ActionBar only to show the three stripes (DrawerIndicator) and the title, but no matter how I try to do this, it only show title or title and app icon AND drawer indicator.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same thing - the way I got around it is I created a 1x1 transparent image to be used as the app icon. That way you only see drawer icon (three grey lines) and the ActionBar title.